# Fail to Append due to Key Violations

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

This is my first time developing a database and first time using MS Access! I am trying to append 1 new record to a table via a form linked to a query.

```
Private Sub cmdAdjustStock_Click()
'Declare Vars
Dim newqty As Long
Dim Qty As Control
Dim change As Control
Dim BoxType As Control
Dim sql As String

'Set form controls to vars
Set Qty = Forms!formMain!txtQty
Set change = Forms!formMain!txtQtyChange
Set BoxType = Forms!formMain!txtBoxType

'Arithmetic and SQL
newqty = Qty + change
sql = "INSERT INTO tblHistory (BoxType, QtyChange, NewQty) VALUES ('&BoxType&','&change&','&newqty&')"

MsgBox "New Quantity = " & newqty & ", Box Type = " & BoxType 'For Debugging
DoCmd.RunSQL sql

End Sub
```

"tblHistory" has the following fields: PID, logDate, BoxType, QtyChange, NewQty. All fields required. "logDate" default value = Date() and PID is autonumber. "tblHistory" currently has no records and this append would be the first!

"BoxType" is on the many end of a 1-many relationship to a table "tblBoxList" containing master list of BoxType (Primary) and their corresponding quantities.

My MsgBox displays correct quantity values and a BoxType from the form (ie. 'RMA-834') matching a Primary BoxType ('RMA-834') on the "tblBoxList".

After verifying the data via the MsgBox the Append fails due to 1 key violation. Im assuming this violation has to do with either the PID (which is an auto increment number) or the BoxType im passing from the form somehow isnt matching up to the primary in tblBoxList. Which is confusing because MsgBox is displaying a value that looks identical to the Primary.

FYI: Tables in this project are linked. I have the 3 tables in a "back-end" on the network. This is the "Front End" with just forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the `INSERT` statement you're asking Access to execute.

```vb
sql = "INSERT INTO tblHistory (BoxType, QtyChange, NewQty) VALUES ('&BoxType&','&change&','&newqty&')"
Debug.Print sql
```

Run the code and examine the `INSERT` statement in the Immediate window.  You can go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

And you can copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing, which should help you diagnose the problem.  Paste the statement text into your question if you need more help from us.

Also consider converting the `INSERT` to a parameter query.  You can use that named query in your VBA code and supply the parameter values at run time.

Assuming you created and tested a parameter query similar to the one below, you named it *qryHistoryAppend*, and it includes *pBoxType*, *pQtyChange*, and *pNewQty* as the named parameters, you can open that query (`QueryDef` object) in VBA, supply the parameter values and execute it.

```vb
Const cstrQuery As String = "qryHistoryAppend"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(cstrQuery)
qdf.Parameters("pBoxType") = Forms!formMain!txtBoxType
qdf.Parameters("pQtyChange") = Forms!formMain!txtQtyChange
qdf.Parameters("pNewQty") = Forms!formMain!txtQty
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError ' <- always use Execute instead of DoCmd.RunSQL
```

Note if that code is contained in *formMain*, you can reference the text boxes like  `Me!txtBoxType` instead of `Forms!formMain!txtBoxType`

My idea for *qryHistoryAppend* looks like this.  Adjust as needed.

```sql
INSERT INTO tblHistory (BoxType, QtyChange, NewQty)
VALUES (pBoxType, pQtyChange, pNewQty);
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. The variables  i thought i was passing to the sql statement was not so. How am i able to pass off the values of my locally declared, input dependent, variables as SQL Append parameters? @HansUp Thx a bunch!

Comment: Just an FYI. Ive been having a terrible time with object referencing in vba (Probably cuz im a noob). Anyway, before i surrounded the parameters with '&BoxType&' i was just calling them as "..Values (BoxType,) "etc... And i would b prompted at runtime only for the 'change' and 'newqty' values and could succesfully append new record. Now my understanding of object referencing with access/vba is completely mind melted haha. @hansUp

Comment: I cant thank you enough for prodding me in the right direction! I found this Microsoft article [Everything About Using Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa160564%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Comment: You're welcome.  If you still encounter any key violations, compare the insert values with those already stored in fields which have a unique index (the primary key is one type, but not the only one).  And if the table has a relationship defined and enforced, failures there can also trigger the key violation error.

Comment: Is it possible to refer to the field parameter of `SET` in an `UPDATE...SET...WHERE` query?

Comment: Or would changing the `qdf.sql` at runtime be a solution? @hansUp

Comment: Not  sure I understand.  You can create an `UPDATE` as a parameter query.  But I suspect it will be easier for you to create, test, and save that `UPDATE` and then use that from VBA compared to altering `qdf.SQL` of the `INSERT` query.  Did that address what you asked?

Comment: I have the update query working by modifying the `SET QTY =` part of the `UPDATE` statement at runtime. I wasnt able to refer to the field that `SET` is looking for as a `qdf.parameter`

Comment: OK, I think I get it now.  Right, you can do `SET BoxType = pBoxType` ... use a parameter to supply the replacement value, but you can't use a parameter for the name of the target field.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblHistory (BoxType, QtyChange, NewQty) VALUES ('&BoxType&','&change&','&newqty&')"
```

Try changing it to:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblHistory (BoxType, QtyChange, NewQty) VALUES ('" & BoxType & "','" & change & "','" & newqty & "')"
```

Comment: This is where majority of my problems lie. How to properly reference objects. Can you explain to me the difference between `'&BoxType&' `and `'" & BoxType &"'` @Johnny Bones

Comment: Your variables have to go **outside** of your quotes.  You first close the quote, then surround your variable with ampersands, then re-open the quote.  It's hard for me to explain, but once you recognize the pattern it makes perfect sense.  You use single quotes if your variable returns a text, and no quotes if it returns an integer.  So, if BoxType was an integer it would be " & BoxType & " and if it is a text it would be ' " & BoxType & " ' (without the extra space between the single and double quote, I just put them in so you could see them).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it sounds like the VB code you show here is irrelevant. Open the database file in MS Access and make the query work within Access first.

Comment: I would love to be able to make this work without using VBA. I was unable to figure out how to reference query-bound form control values and append them to a 3rd table 'tblHistory'( Such as my form control 'txtBoxType' that is bound to a inner join query of tables 'tblCaseList' and 'tblBoxList' on 'BoxType') as parameters to an SQL append string. Thus my deference to using the "code builder" to pass the form control values to local sub variables and then reference those in my sql append string.